# Efficient adapter has java.lang.ClassCastException?

Tags: android, android-adapter

After watching [here](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) I try to implement my own efficient adapter,

My ViewHolder class almost same:

```
static class ViewHolder {
        ImageButton button;
        TextView txtView;
    }
```

getView method look like:

```
private void getView(...) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(
                parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.linear_container,
                        parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // erro line
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    LinearLayout llCustomImgViewContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
    llCustomImgViewContainer.setTag(viewPosition);

    return converView;
}
```

but here once new view started to draw, it give me error

D/AndroidRuntime(  748): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  748): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412a4300)
E/AndroidRuntime(  748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  748): **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.droid.test.widget.customListView$CustomBaseAdapter$ViewHolder**

any one have idea what is wrong here?

Comment: I'm sorry [link](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) no more exist :-/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that at first with

```
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

line you are setting the tag(which is holder) associated with this view but later with

```
llCustomImgViewContainer.setTag(viewPosition);
```

you are setting viewPosition as a tag. Then probably in

```
holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
```

your code trying to cast Integer to ViewHolder and throws a java.lang.ClassCastException.

If I'm not wrong and this is the structure of the "linear_container" layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/llContainer">

    <!-- some views -->

</LinearLayout>
```

The view returned from

```
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.linear_container,parent,false);
```

and the view returned from

```
convertView.findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
```

should be same.

Comment: yes for above both answer...convertView and llCustomImgViewContainer both are two different view...so both should be independent.

Comment: I updated my answer. If I guessed right, this may explain why these views are dependent.

Comment: ahhha...got idea...how I missed this. well explanation thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting an int instead of the view :

```
llCustomImgViewContainer.setTag(viewPosition);
```

When you use setTag, you save the given object (viewPosition), in the calling object (llCustomImgViewContainer).

Remove the last line :

```
llCustomImgViewContainer.setTag(viewPosition);
```